# Capybara - visit() not working with firefox

Tags: firefox, capybara

I'm a noob in cucumber and capybara, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to setup a cucumber project that uses chrome and firefox as the test platform. So far, I have got the test to work on chrome, but not on firefox.

Below is the code snippet:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'fileutils'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/throttle.rb'

#CAPYBARA
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/session'
#require 'capybara-webkit'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_firefox do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end

driver = case ENV['BROWSER']
when 'chrome'
  :chrome
when 'firefox'
  :selenium_firefox
when 'webkit'
  :webkit
when 'ie'
  :internet_explorer
else
  :chrome
end

Capybara.default_driver         = driver
Capybara.javascript_driver      = :selenium_firefox
Capybara.run_server             = false
Capybara.default_selector       = :css
```

Then, for the test, I just simply did a visit("http://www.google.com").

If I set my browser parameter to chrome, it worked fine. Cucumber openned up chrome and automatically typed in "www.google.com", and the page loaded without a problem.

However, the moment I set it to firefox: $cucumber features/test.feature BROWSER=firefox, it didn't work. It did open up the firefox browser, but nothing was being automatically typed into the URL box.

So, I must be missing something in the setup process that I'm not aware of. I have been looking for solutions on the web (require 'selenium webdriver', put 'selenium webdriver' into my Gemfiles, etc.), but so far none has worked for me.

What am I missing here? How come visit() didn't automatically populate the URL box of firefox, but it did just fine with chrome?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you got a solution?